# How to read ViewModel data from sttrings.xml list of items

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I am trying to build a recyclerview app which takes data from strings.xml file.

```
In the below code I hardcoded the name1 & name2, where I would like to get the content of name1 & name2 from the strings.xml file


    val name1 = listOf<String>("lkjlkjlk","jkljlkjl","jlkjlkjl","jlkjlkj","jlkjlkj")
    val name2 = listOf<String>("iuoiuoi","jkljlkjl","jlkjlkjl","jlkjlkj","jlkjlkj")

Please guide me in getting the name1 & name2 from the strings.xml file
```

Comment: Extending from ViewModel allows you to pass Contaxt as a Parameter to your class. Then you can use context.getString() or context.getResources().getString()

Comment: are you trying to read this from the viewmodel or the recyclerview ?

Comment: @DanielSpiess there is no reason to be passing in context to your viewmodel if you can get these strings from the activity and instead pass that to the viewmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a string-array in the strings.xml resources, using the **resources.getStringArray** function to retrieve the values. Example (note that the MainActivity is passed as a parameter to provide access to resources):

```
package ...
import ...

class RecyclerNameAdapter (private val mainActivity: MainActivity): RecyclerView.Adapter<ListItemHolder>() {

    val Name1Content: Array<String> = mainActivity.resources.getStringArray(R.array.name1)
    val Name2Content: Array<String> = mainActivity.resources.getStringArray(R.array.name2)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListItemHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.recycler_name_layout, parent, false)
        return ListItemHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return   Name1Content.size         
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.view.txtName1.text = Name1Content[position]
        holder.view.txtName2.text = Name2Content[position]
        }
   }
}

class ListItemHolder (val view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        init {
            view.isClickable = false
        }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @PhilW It helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can define string array in `strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="arr_fruits">
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Mango</item>
</string-array>
```

Get this array inside `Activity`

```
val fruits = resources.getStringArray(R.array.arr_fruits)
```